# mini-kanren what is the difference between cond-a cond-u and cond-e?

Tags: clojure, prolog, the-little-schemer, minikanren

I have tried to use an implementation of mini-kanren in clojure. But been struggling to understand the difference between cond-a cond-u and cond-e. I seem to be quite clear about cond-e but understanding of cond-a and cond-u is quiet bad.

cond-e takes a set of goals and then tries each of them... i.e tries all the branches that succeed.

cond-a and cond-u on the contrary commit to the branch whose first predicate succeeds and cond-a returns all the possible successful unifications there after. while cond-u returns only the first successfull unification ... but however it seems like this understanding is not correct when I use it. Can somebody help me clarify this understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cond-e gives every answer from all branches that succeed

cond-i gives every answer but interleaves them.

cond-a only gives the answers from the first successful branch

cond-u only gives the first answer from the first successful branch

Comment: Thanks Jim.. But What exactly is interleaving ? is it like it gets one successful answer from each branch .. before coming back to the first branch for the next successful answer... ?

Comment: according to your explaination the following code should behave the same whether I use cond-u or cond-a in place of cond-?                  (run q
     (exist [x]
            (cond-?
             ((& x :unassigned)
              fail)
             (succeed)) 
            (& q 20))) But that does not seem to be the case .... can you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

I was just trying to get my head around these matters. There's a shortified scheme implementation
[Sokuza-kanren](http://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/sokuza-kanren.scm) with a few comments, I'll read it tonight.

Comment: It was very enlightening to read the Sokuza-kanren implementation. Thanks for the link.