# Prolog sublists generation, multiply empty list - don't know why

Tags: prolog, append, sublist

I want to make prolog returning me all possible sublists of given list so I wrote:

```
subSet(L,S):- append(_,L2,L),append(S,_,L2).
```

In that way I get result like:

```
Out = [] ;
Out = [a] ;
Out = [a, b] ;
Out = [a, b, c] ;
Out = [] ;
Out = [b] ;
Out = [b, c] ;
Out = [] ;
Out = [c] ;
Out = [] ;
```

What I have to do to get rid of repeating empty list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule out that you are describing the empty list at all and add it manually once.

```
list_subseq(_,[]).
list_subseq(L, S) :- S = [_|_], ....
```

Nevertheless, expressing subsequences is often better done with DCGs. See the first definition in  [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686307/772868). Using `append/3` might work, but leads to code that is quite difficult to read.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is a [`sublist`](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc214) predicate among the standard list predicates already (which only lists `[]` once). I'll assume that you're implementing this as an exercise...

---

An empty list is always a sublist, so this can be specified explicitly. You can then avoid the empty list by using `[S|T]` instead of `S`:

```
subSet(_, []).
subSet(L, [S|T]) :- append(_, L2,L), append([S|T], _, L2).
```

**Example run:**

```
| ?- subSet([a, b, c], Out).

Out = [] ? ;

Out = [a] ? ;

Out = [a,b] ? ;

Out = [a,b,c] ? ;

Out = [b] ? ;

Out = [b,c] ? ;

Out = [c] ? ;
```

Comment: Ok, Nice that works, but what kind of diffrence makes if i do [S|T] instead of S ?? I mean I know that stands for Not Empty List here, But is there any other way to do that?

Comment: The difference is that `S` can bind to `[]`, while `[S|T]` can not. You could of course easily define a `nonempty([_|_]).` predicate and do `nonempty(S)` I think using `[S|T]` directly is the standard way of doing it.

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to a `sublist` predicate btw.