# Divide List to pieces of needed length

Tags: prolog, dcg

I was trying to write predicate `divide(L,Len,Slist)` which will be true when Slist can unify with a List of length Len allocated from List L. for example

```
divide([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],3,Slist).
```

Should give such answers

```
Slist=[1,2,3];
Slist=[2,3,4];
Slist=[3,4,5];
Slist=[4,5,6];
Slist=[5,6,7];
```

But i couldn't find a better way then `length(X,Len), sublist(L,X).` but it does work too slow.
How should look divide predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sublist/2 doesn't seems to work as expected:

```
?- [library(dialect/sicstus/lists)].
% library(dialect/sicstus/lists) compiled into sicstus_lists 0,00 sec, 14 clauses
true.

?- L=[1,2,3,4,5,6], length(T, 3),sublist(T,L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
T = [1, 2, 3] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
T = [1, 2, 4] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
T = [1, 2, 5] ;
....
```

You could use append/3 instead:

```
?- L=[1,2,3,4,5,6], length(T, 3), append(_, Q, L), append(T, _, Q).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
T = [1, 2, 3],
Q = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
T = [2, 3, 4],
Q = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
T = [3, 4, 5],
Q = [3, 4, 5, 6] ;
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
T = Q, Q = [4, 5, 6] ;
false.
```

I don't think it's very fast, just essential...

Comment: it does work for me 4 ?- length(X,3),sublist([1,2,3,4,5],X).
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
X = [1, 2, 4] ;
X = [1, 2, 5] ;...

Comment: try with sublist([],[]).
sublist([X|T], [X|TS]) :- sublist(T, TS).
sublist([_|T], X) :- sublist(T, X).

Comment: Yes it is because i'm working on long lists and i'm not interested with all sublist just with all 4-length lists allocated from my List

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use DCG as mentionned by @false in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684549/prolog-list-plateau/9686307#9686307):

```
seq([])     --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).

divide(List, Length, Result) :-
    length(Result, Length),
    phrase((seq(_), seq(Result), seq(_)), List).
```